# Get and post new attribute values

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I want to add new attribute values in attributes like Color,size dynamically through API.
like if any new color comes in data then we can add through api. please help me to provide get attribute value and post attribute values.

Comment: Can you please describe in more details what you are looking?

Comment: Suppose I have attribute Color and dropdown value I added is WHite and Green. Now, when I push data through product creation API, color comes Black. Here I want that Black color should automatically add in COlor dropdown and my product is created successfully with Black color.